# Meteor: how do I create a post insert hook?

Tags: meteor

I'm using [autoform](https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-autoform) to create forms.  I have the template below which is correctly inserting data into the collection when the form is submitted.  What I want to do is insert a record into another collection when the insert into the "ContactDetails" collection has been completed successfully.

```
<template name="contactDetailsForm">
 {{#if submitted}}
    {{> quickForm collection="ContactDetails" omitFields="createdBy" doc=editingDoc id="contactDetailsForm" type="update"}}
 {{else}}
         {{> quickForm collection="ContactDetails" omitFields="createdBy" id="contactDetailsForm" type="insert"}}
 {{/if}}
</template>
```

As far as I know I would need to add a hook.  I'm really not sure what I'm doing with this.  I'd imagine it would look something like this:

```
  AutoForm.addHooks(['contactDetailsForm'], {
    after: {
      insert: function(error, result) {
        if (error) {
        console.log("Insert Error:", error);
        } else {
        console.log("Insert Result:", result);
        // NOW DO INSERT INTO OTHER COLLECTION
        }
      }
    }
});
```

Can anyone show me how to insert a record into another collection after an insert has been successfully completed in a different collection?

Any advice/help/examples on this would be sincerely appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`matb33:collection-hooks`](https://github.com/matb33/meteor-collection-hooks) package is a standard way to create such hooks. First add it with

```
meteor add matb33:collection-hooks
```

Then create your hook:

```
ContactDetails.after.insert(function(userId, doc) {
  console.log("Inserted:", this._id);
  ...
});
```

Comment: How can I get this to work on the client?  I would like to set a session variable, but get the Session not defined error - 500.

Comment: @DeBraid, where is your code located, in `client` folder or in shared location? Do you see the error in the browser console?

Comment: Nothing in the browser console, have `Foo.after.insert(...)` on the client side a few places here, but broken. https://github.com/DeBraid/tracyandderek/commit/2db8d85ac5d1dd8fd7c533b9e5b5e9c99f012a39 Nothing in JS console, does however run on the server.

Answer (score 1):

In general the hooks are not available yet - but they are in autoform:
https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-autoform#callbackshooks

If you were not using autoform I would do the insert with a Meteor method, where you could just do the after insert, after you inserted the first one.
See this https://www.discovermeteor.com/blog/meteor-methods-client-side-operations/

Comment: collection-hooks is also worth mentioning https://github.com/matb33/meteor-collection-hooks